# h1のfont-sizeは親要素を継承しないのでしょうか？

Tags: html, css

下記のコードを書いてみました。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    aaaaaaa
    <h1>h</h1>
    bbbb
</body>
</html>
```

結果:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Chromeデベロッパーツール:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デベロッパーツールを見ると、ユーザーエージェントのスタイルシートが適用されてしまっているのがわかります。

ネットを見ると `border`は継承されないと書いている例をみますが、`font-size`は継承されると言及しているページを多くみます。確かに htmlの子要素であるbody要素には継承されていますが、h1は例外なのでしょうか？（ほかにh2にも試しましたが、やはり継承されていませんでした）

なお

```
h1 {
    font: inherit;
}
```

をCSSに加えると継承しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

継承されていますが、ユーザーエージェントのスタイルシートによるh1要素へのスタイル指定で上書きされています。
その要素へのスタイル指定は、親から継承されたものよりもユーザーエージェントのスタイルシートによるものが優先されるからです。

> なお
>
> ```css
> h1 {
>    font: inherit;
> }
> ```
>
> をCSSに加えると継承しました。

これはh1要素へ親から継承するように指定しているので、ユーザーエージェントのスタイルシートの指定よりも優先されます。